# Why is "late" used in reference to a deceased person?

Tags: etymology

I get how and when it's used but what is its origin?

Why the word "late"?

Comment: What does the etymology listing in your dictionary tell you?

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Late&searchmode=none

Comment: It connects through the idea ***recently*** as in ***lately***. We tend to use that expression for a short time after people die. So he died recently = late.

Comment: We also use it more generally to mean *recently*: "I'd like to introduce Bill Williams, late of XYZ Corp., who will be heading up our research department."

Answer (score 3):

**"the late Mr X"** -  This use of "late" is elliptical for lately deceased (recently deceased).

> an ellipsis is the act of leaving out one or more words that are not necessary for a phrase to be understood. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis)
>
> etymology of "late" - The sense of "deceased" (as in the late Mrs. Smith) is from late 15c., from an adverbial sense of "recently." Of women's menstrual periods, attested colloquially from 1962. Related: Lateness. As an adverb, from Old English late. [ED](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=late&searchmode=term)